# git merge -s ours includes irrelevant commits

Tags: git, merge

When I merge a branch using the ours strategy, even though the codeline does not change, I end up with a whole lot of new commit messages that I am not interested in (since they have no impact on my codeline.) Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Doesn't the *ours* strategy only affect conflicts, not the rest of the merge? It doesn't seem like it would stop commits of other sections of the code from being merged into your branch ...

Comment: It's the expected behaviour of `-s ours`, introducing the history without the changes. If you don't want the history of the branch, why would you merge it this way?

Comment: What's a codeline in reference to git?

Comment: I want the history so that git knows about it for future merges. I just don't want to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [ElpieKay noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785349/git-merge-s-ours-includes-irrelevant-commits#comment96349272_54785349), it really is supposed to work this way: `git merge -s ours` makes a new *merge commit* that uses the same *snapshot* as the current commit.  But being a merge commit means that the new commit has two *parent* commits: the previously-current commit as its first parent, and the other commit—the one you merged—as its second parent:

```
...--F--G--H--M   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
             /
 ...--J--K--L
```

When you run `git log`, `git log`'s job is to follow *all* the parents, showing their log messages, *unless you tell it not to:*

```
git log --first-parent
```

This tells Git that at each merge, such as `M`, it should follow only the *first* parent.  After showing `M`, Git will move back to `H`, not to both `H` and `L`.